# jQuery Ajax posting not working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

My jQuery ajax posting is not working. Here is the javascript

```
function SocialButtons() {  
var $buttonWrapper = jQuery('.WrapperDiv');
if ($buttonWrapper.length){
    var postData = $buttonWrapper.html();
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://www.wordpress-site.com/wp-contents/themes/theme-name/post.php',
        data: postData, 
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) { 
            console.log(data);
        },
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'json'    
    });
}
}
```

I am saving the data to be posted inside a hidden div like

```
<div class='WrapperDiv hidden'>{"post_id":392,"url":"http:\/\/www.wordpress-site\/post\/post-title\/","title":"SEO Friendly title"}</div>
```

All I am getting in return from the post.php page is an empty array. Here is my code for post.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST)){
    print_r($_POST);
} else {
    echo "0";
}   
?>
```

Any Idea whats wrong?

**EDIT : Its working after I removed**

```
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'json'
```

Comment: the html grabbed would just be a string? you need to create a real array from that.

Comment: postData is just a string, not an object. When using strings, the string would have to be built as a querystring, not JSON.

Comment: @adeneo : any fiddle?

Comment: Something like : `<div class='WrapperDiv hidden'>?post_id=392&url=http:\\www.wordpress-site\post\post-title\&title=SEO%20Friendly%20title</div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working after I removed

```
contentType: "application/json",
dataType: 'json'
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
var postData = "data=" + encodeURCIComponent($buttonWrapper.html());
```

Than in PHP:

```
echo $_POST["data"];
```

Than parse it or something....

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to try,

**Try to pass the data directly in to the data object first. If it
 works then you can debug and see why it's not ready your hidden div.**

**instead of $buttonWrapper.html try $buttonWrapper.text();**

```
function SocialButtons() {  
var $buttonWrapper = jQuery('.WrapperDiv');
if ($buttonWrapper.length){
    var postData = $buttonWrapper.**text**();
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://www.wordpress-site.com/wp-contents/themes/theme-name/post.php',
        data: **{'id':1}**, 
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) { 
            console.log(data);
        },
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'json'    
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your jQuery ajax call, your data is not set to $_POST variable names. Hence why nothing is showing

Try changing your function to this:

```
function SocialButtons() {  
  var buttonWrapper = jQuery('.WrapperDiv');
  if (buttonWrapper.length){
    var postData = buttonWrapper.html();
    jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://www.wordpress-site.com/wp-contents/themes/theme-name/post.php',
    data: {postData: postData}, 
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) { 
        console.log(data);
    },
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'json'    
    });
  }
}
```

Then you should have a `$_POST['postData']` variable on your `print_r` or `var_dump` of `$_POST`.

Comment: @rahulRam See my edit. Take out '$' in front of buttonWrapper, and see if that works.